# Netcool/Omnibus Active Event List Summary

Tags: tivoli

I use Netcool OMNIbus to forward alerts from  IBM Tivoli Monitoring (ITM). There are active event lists and summaries in there. How can I change the summary value with my own default information to get easier read reason?

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend modifying the alert summary value close to the source of the alert, in this case the IBM Tivoli Monitoring (ITM) Situation.  ITM situations are mapped to Netcool/OMNIbus alerts using the Event Integration Facility (EIF).

The ITM to Netcool/OMNIbus integration is described in '[Setting up event forwarding to OMNIbus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3JRN_7.2.1/com.ibm.itm.doc_6.3/install/omnibus_install.htm)'

In particular look at the section '[Default mapping of situation events to OMNIbus events](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3JRN_7.2.1/com.ibm.itm.doc_6.3/install/mapevent_omni.htm)'

Which shows that the EIF msg attribute is mapped to the Summary field of the alert.  It depends on what you are trying to do, but one solution would be to modify the ITM Situation so that the message attribute contains the summary that you require.

Another approach may be to modify the Summary field in the OMNIbus EIF probe rules file.  Changes made here would be appropriate if you wanted to make a change that affected all Situations forwarded from ITM, e.g. if you wished to add a prefix string to the summary.  See the 'Netcool/OMNIbus EIF Probe User guide' for more detail on the probe and rules file.